# Plotting from CSV file using comma as decimal separator

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to create a plot with pgfplots from CSV file using semicolon as separator and comma as period.

I've tried parsing `/pgf/number format/read comma as period` as parameter to both `\axis` and `\addplot`.

When used in `\axis` the parameter is ignored and error occurs, indicating need of `read comma as period` argument.

When used in `\addplot` I receive :
[image: received error]

I'm using MixTex 2.9.6888.

My code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots,siunitx}
\usepackage[lotdepth]{subfig}
\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
    Column1;MERENI;FI2;URMS2
    ;1;3,006;17,86
    ;2;3,997;20,49
    ;3;5,006;22,86
    ;4;6,009;25,31
    ;5;7,001;27,85
    ;6;8,005;30,52
    ;7;9,014;33,19
    ;8;10,001;35,99
    ;9;11,01;38,73
    ;10;12,005;41,52
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            [
            width=\linewidth,
            grid=major,
            grid style={dashed,gray!30},
            title={mytitle},
            ylabel=$U_[ef]$,
            xlabel=$f$,
            %/pgf/number format/read comma as period,
            y unit=\si{\volt},
            x unit=\si{\hertz},
            ymin = 0, xmin = 0      
            ]
            \addplot table[x=FI2, y=URMS2, col sep=semicolon, /pgf/number format/read comma as period] {data.csv};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{figure}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome, what is the column separator, what is the period sign?

Comment: semicolon as column separator, comma as period

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending (naïvely, I must admit) scrolling the logs looking for "*why can't `pgfplots` read my table*", I found out that the problem is not at all related to the format of your data table. Actually, the exact same error shows up if you compile this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ylabel=$U_[ef]$]
      \addplot coordinates {(0,0)(1,1)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This will break because the `axis` environment takes an optional argument delimited by `[`...`]`. When scanning for the `]` delimiter TeX will take the first `]` that is in the same nesting level (*i.e.* not inside braces), and the one which fits the requirement is the closing bracket in `U_[ef]`, so the text passed to `axis` will be `ylabel=$U_[ef` which will unbalance the `$`...`$` then stuff will break.

To fix this you have to hide the `]` in brackets like this:

```
\begin{axis}[ylabel=$U_{[ef]}$]% DO use this
```

this one

```
\begin{axis}[{{ylabel=$U_[ef]$}}]% Don't use this
```

and even this one

```
\begin{axis}[ylabel=$U_[ef{]}$]% Don't use this
```

will compile too, but the output will not be as expected, and the syntax is dubious, at least.

You are also missing the `units` library to use `x unit` and `y unit`. It'll work after that:

> [image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,siunitx}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
    Column1;MERENI;FI2;URMS2
    ;1;3,006;17,86
    ;2;3,997;20,49
    ;3;5,006;22,86
    ;4;6,009;25,31
    ;5;7,001;27,85
    ;6;8,005;30,52
    ;7;9,014;33,19
    ;8;10,001;35,99
    ;9;11,01;38,73
    ;10;12,005;41,52
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
      [
        width=\linewidth,
        grid=major,
        grid style={dashed,gray!30},
        title={mytitle},
        ylabel=$U_{[ef]}$,
        xlabel=$f$,
        %/pgf/number format/read comma as period,
        y unit=\si{\volt},
        x unit=\si{\hertz},
        ymin = 0, xmin = 0
      ]
      \addplot table[x=FI2, y=URMS2, col sep=semicolon, /pgf/number format/read comma as period] {data.csv};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I completely missed the brackets. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @hlavir You're welcome :) This is actually an interesting issue. I don't think `pgfplots` should break with this input (even if it's actually incorrect). Perhaps it's a bug. I'll investigate later.

Comment: I think that the problem is commented somewhere in `pgfkeys`: if you have a `]` in a key argument, you must include it in braces, otherwise the bracket is seen as closing the options, and havoc arises...

Comment: I agree to Rmano's comment. This is a general LaTeX problem I think. *Always* when you have optional arguments and the argument (itself) contains a closing square bracket it is seen as the closing bracket for the optional argument. To avoid this, on has to enclose the argument (parts) in curly brackets.

Comment: @StefanPinnow I agree, optional argument handling _is_ fragile. However, I wouldn't expect this to happen because in this particular case the brackets are handled by `pgfkeys` correctly (supposedly) because the delimiters here are `,` and `=`. It only breaks when the `ylabel` is used. I think that whatever package is responsible for this part should secure the argument to `ylabel` so that argument handling is not compromised. For me (not knowing how the code works) it looks more like a misfeature than a limitation of the method. I might be judging wrong, of course.

Comment: Maybe you are right. But I would bet (without testing) that every value (to a key) that allows "free text" (and not a value from a list of allowed values) will behave the same. If you really think this is a bug one of us should add this to the [pgf bug tracker](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/).

Comment: @StefanPinnow Forget it, now I _actually_ read Rmano's comment and yes, that's the reason, you were both right (of course) and there's not much to do on the package side. I rushed into conclusions, as always ;)